# convert CURL get request to guzzlehttp client Laravel

Tags: laravel, curl, guzzle

This is the curl that I want to execute:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-ABC-Application-Id: 12345asdfg" \
-H "X-ABC-REST-API-Key: 12345asdfg" \
-G \
--data-urlencode "where={ \"SKU\":\"A string\",\"QTY\":1 }" \
example.com/product/inventory
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$endpoint = "example.com";
$client = new Client();

$body = ['where' => ['SKU' => 'A string']];

$headers = [
'X-ABC-Application-Id' => '12345asdfg',
'X-ABC-REST-API-Key' => '12345asdfg'
 ];

$response = $client->get($endpoint, [
'query' => $body,
'headers' => $headers,
]);

$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
$content = $response->getBody();
dd($statusCode,$content,$response);
```

After executing it I got an error (exception) as follows:

`400 Bad Request` response:

```json
{"code":102,"error":"Invalid parameter for query: 0"}
```

Comment: What does `Http::dd()->your->other->stuff()` output? (of course replace `->your->other->stuff` with the stuff from the question)

Comment: i am getting exception 400 bad request. you can see the error message in the last line of my question

Comment: I don't want to see the response, I want to see the request to compare it with your curl command. There's probably something missing (maybe Content-Type header or the like)

Comment: i have shared with you complete request data. it has endpoint, method, header and data. i am not sure what else you want. this is a third party API and i have pasted as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The misconception is that `get()` doesn't take headers. You have to pass them by calling `withHeaders()` before you fire the request and only pass `$body` directly as the second parameter to `get()` without wrapping it into an array.

```
$endpoint = "example.com";
$client = new Client();

$body = ['where' => ['SKU' => 'A string']];

$headers = [
'X-ABC-Application-Id' => '12345asdfg',
'X-ABC-REST-API-Key' => '12345asdfg'
 ];

$response = $client->withHeaders($headers)->get($endpoint, $body);

$statusCode = $response->getStatusCode();
$content = $response->getBody();
dd($statusCode,$content,$response);
```